# Encoding and Decoding in a certain range of values

Tags: python

My code is almost done, I'm just struggling with a certain part of the decode/encode. When I try to encode ABC by 28 it returns symbols rather than letters. However, it works with lowercase letters. I'm not entirely sure how to fix it and I'm seeking some help. I'm not trying to drastically change my code, rather keep it as it is I think I'm just missing the correct values or operations.

Here's my current code:

```
def encode_or_decode(encode_or_decode_choice, str_to_change, key):

 if encode_or_decode_choice == "encode":
    new_str = ""
    for i in range(len(str_to_change)):
        shifter = ord(str_to_change[i])
        shift1 = key
        if shifter + shift1 > 122:
            shift1 = shift1 - (122 - shifter)
            shift1 = shift1 % 26
            new_str = new_str + chr(shift1 + 96)
        elif shifter + shift1 < 90:
            shift1 = shift1 - (90 - shifter)
            shift1 = shift1 % 26
            new_str = new_str + chr(shift1 + 64)
        else:
            new_str = new_str + chr(shifter + key)
    return new_str

 elif encode_or_decode_choice == "decode":
    new_str = ""
    for i in range(len(str_to_change)):
        shifter = ord(str_to_change[i])
        shift1 = key
        if shifter + shift1 > 122:
            shift1 = shift1 - (122 - shifter)
            shift1 = shift1 % 26
            new_str = new_str + chr(shift1 + 96)
        elif shifter + shift1 > 90:
            shift1 = shift1 - (90 - shifter)
            shift1 = shift1 % 26
            new_str = new_str + chr(shift1 + 64)
        else:
            new_str = new_str + chr(shifter - key)
    return new_str
 else:
    print("Bad Input")
    encode_or_decode_test()

def encode_or_decode_test():
  desc1 = True
  while desc1 == True:
      result = encode_or_decode(str(input("Would you like to encode or decode? ")), str(input("Enter a string: ")), int(input("Enter a key (integer): ")))
      print("Encoding or decoding given word based off decision, by given key:", result)
      decisions = str(input("Would you like to encode or decode again? (y or n) "))
      if decisions == "y":
          desc1 = True
      else:
          desc1 = False


def main():
    encode_or_decode_test()
```

Comment: Assuming you're using [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), `ABC` encoded with key 28 **should** be `CDE`. Key **26** should encode `ABC` as `ABC`.

Comment: Thank you for that I didn't realize. I still have a problem where if I do encode ABC with a key of 28 it puts it into symbols rather than letters. Not sure how I fix this either.

Answer (score 0):

The elif condition in encode should be -

```
elif shifter + shift1 > 90:
```

Comment: This fixed that problem, but now created the problem of putting in encode for abc by a key of 2 where it now prints IJK instead of cde.

Comment: Code in question with above change only print cde for encoding of abc with key=2. You might have different version running on your system.